# Should I report the business conduct ethics violation?

Tags: company-policy

I have a case, backed up with e-mails which points out that our big, international corporation, for one of it's projects which would cost up to 10mil $ in a long run, gives a preference to the supplier which comes recommended by our CEO. The supplier brings no expertise, no value, nothing to the table and every person from the "floor" who would have to work on the project agrees with this and sees no benefit working with this supplier.

Couple of people in high management, stated in the e-mails to a small group (me included) that they want to still chose that supplier due to the CEO recommendation to win his approvals.

Yearly we go through the re-signing (signing the updated version) of the business policies internally where it stated to always have a fair selection, never do preferences based on "friendships" and so on.

We also have a system in place to report such actions - it's a quite detailed form where everything has to be stated with names, dates, details.

My concern here is that this supplier involvement is taking the work from the hands of the employees who want and can do it and everyone from the management agrees with that, but still only for the "comes recommended" part  want to contract the supplier for almost years ahead which would eventually result in a lot of money paid for people just "walking around" and just to "please the ceo" that his friends are sorted out now.

I want to report that! I even have secretly reported a meeting where this was voiced once. So i have the facts, but I am seriously afraid for my job and any other forms of further harassment.  I was openly objecting this motion, but couldn't overrule it so if anything comes now from the legal angle - even my anonymous report would point to me eventually.

I can of course let it go, but it just professionally painful to observe and extremely de-motivational for other employees.

Anyone had experience with such cases? How does this go? Is the fight of a small man vs. big corp - worth it?

Comment: Does the system you have in place to report the actions deal with the fact that people might not want to have any problems in the future if they report? A first step would be to figure out how anonymously (from your side) this could be done.

Comment: Do you have a compliance officer at your company?

Comment: Well the system is setup very strictly with tons of policies attached and taking into account local laws which apply to privacy, information sharing and so on. 

System ( website with a  form) - offers me to stay anonymous and guarantees the company commitment to protect me legally from any forms of harassment.

But that's just words on the website...

And if after my report anyone comes asking questions about that supplier - it would be very clear to those who are involved that it's me who blew the whistle. So much for anonymity...

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ good point. looking for that person now. probably we do. What if that person figures that it can go big and decides to actually shut it rather than pursue...then i'm sort of exposed...

Comment: If it's a big enough company, you should have a compliance officer and a policy that allows for anonymous reporting.  This is exactly why they're there.  I'm not saying that what's happening is illegal, but the CO will be able to say for certain that the practice is legal & ethical or not - it's their job.

Comment: You need to ask if your job is more important than your ethics. Reporting something like this will never be anonymous. There is always a way to track it. Even if there are laws to protect you, a way can be found.

Comment: @Snowlockk I'm not just driven by the blind pursue of justice. There are things happening daily which probably can be reported, but in this very case - it will also result in my team no being doing a proper work and that also upsets me professionally too. So at the end of the day it's even not just ethics - it's work.

Comment: @GeekSince1982 Yes it's work. Reporting it would likely result in you being removed from employment for one reason or another. If you really depend on the paycheck then it's best to keep quite and ignore it. If it's as big a thing as you mention the person in charge of dealing with it knows about it and is either doing something about it or worse allowing it to happen.

Comment: If this comes from the CEO and managers are complying then yes it is a problem but it is not your problem.

Comment: @Paparazzi that's how i inclined to see this at this point... too big of a fight from my position and it's really me vs 3+ high level managers who would clearly figure it out who has "snitched" :)

Comment: @Snowlockk life is unfair:) i am sure they'll come back at me. they have more to loose from their higher management positions with bonuses and stuf.

Comment: @GeekSince1982 They will most likely get a slap on the wrist while you lose your job.

Comment: @Paparazzi that depends on the laws in his area.  Sometimes knowing, and not reporting can be a criminal act.  If it's a heavily regulated industry, doubly so.

Comment: My previous boss was in a situation similar to this, where the major share holder instructed him to pick this specific supplier where those peoples did not have any expertise to our field. He refused it, he got replaced fast by another director. It took almost 6 year for the board members to notice the situation and be able to kick out the major share holder.

Comment: By experience, I rarely see people winning this kind of fight because supporters will flee when blow strikes. So you will probably be alone for the fight, be fire if you are without any upper management assistance and nothing will change. Good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't this system ultimately report to the CEO in question? And are you sure the CEO doesn't have a valid reason he might not be sharing for tactical reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really answer whether you should blow the whistle or not. Neither can I comment on any legal aspects. But I will provide a list of some questions you will want to answer before making your choice. This list is not exhaustive.

---

I would ask myself the following questions. If the answer is **yes**, then that lends weight to whistle-blowing:

- Is the action likely to be illegal?
- Are whistle-blowers protected in your country?
- Would whistle-blowing change the outcome of the decision?
- Are you likely to retain your job and career prospects if you whistle-blow?

---

I would then ask myself the following questions. If the answer is **no**, then that lends weight to not whistle-blow:

- Are you financially stable enough to endure a period of unemployment?
- Are you financially stable enough to endure legal bills?
- Do you have good employment prospects outside of the business?
- Does the decision of which supplier to use effect you beyond ethical objections? E.g. would it reduce your ability to move up within the company?

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on what you have shared in your question no.

Just because a vendor choice is distasteful and perhaps not the optimal choice from where you sit, does not mean that the recommendation was unethical.  The CEO may have criteria and reasons for the recommendation that are entirely business related and ethical.  Unless you can prove or have a really compelling circumstantial case(like the CEO's wife owns the vendor) otherwise it is going really difficult to show any actionable problems.

And while it is possible that the partnership for your specific part may not make a lot of sense it could be that the big picture partnership with the vendor adds, or has the potential to add, significant value to the company.

Wanting to please your boss is also not unethical.  Outsourcing is not unethical.  There is nothing here that is obviously unethical.  That is not saying that you are wrong for having a bad taste in your mouth over the issue, just that that does not add up to unethical behavior.

As a result there is nothing to be gain for you to report.  The results of reporting are certainly a significant risk as while retribution for reporting may be illegal and not supposed to happen, they do anyway and are incredibly hard to prove.

Answer (score -2):

You are in the most unenviable of positions.

Either you put yourself on the line and possibly never work in the industry again, or you remain quiet, which could put you in a possible situation where you are criminally complicit in a conspiracy.

See a lawyer, find out what the whistle-blower laws are in your area, and follow his advice.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  While seek the advice of a lawyer can be the TLDR of an answer, that answer should contain a thorough explanation of why the lawyer is the right course of action.